# Como puedo generar botón activo por CSS cuando selecciona una categoría en un filtrado de productos

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, scss

Hola estoy haciendo este ejemplo de filtrar producto por categoría pero estoy teniendo un problema cuando selecciona una opción del menu izquierdo y el botón no queda activo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".filter-button").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
          
 if(value == "all")
 {
   //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
   $('.filter').show('1000');
 }
 else
 {
   //$('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
  // $(".filter").not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').addClass('hidden');
          $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
    $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');  
 }
    });
});
```

```css
.archive-producto .btn-primary {
  background: #d1c286;
  color: #fff;
  border: initial;
  border-radius: initial;
  border-color: #d8cb98;
}
.archive-producto .btn-primary:hover,.archive-producto .btn-primary:focus,.archive-producto .btn-primary:active {
  background: red !important;
  border-color: initial !important;
}
.archive-producto .btn-primary.btn-outline {
  background: #3d464a;
  color: #fff;
  border: initial;
  padding: 10px 20px !important;
}
.archive-producto ul .btn{
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.archive-producto .port-image{
  width: 100%;
}
.archive-producto .col-md-4{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.product .product-grid {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.product .product-grid .sale {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #c70707;
    color: #fffbfa;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
}
.product .product-grid .inner {
  display: table;
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.product .product-grid .inner p .icon {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #d1c286;
}
.product .product-grid .inner p .icon:hover, .product .product-grid .inner p .icon:focus {
  color: #d1c286;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.product .desc h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.product .desc h3 a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="archive-producto">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="row animate-box">
      <ul class="categoria">
        <li class="btn btn-primary filter-button" data-filter="all">Todos</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary filter-button" data-filter="mesas">Mesas</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary filter-button" data-filter="syb">Sillas y bancos</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary filter-button" data-filter="escritorios">Escritorio</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary filter-button" data-filter="ratonas">Mesa ratonas</li>
        <li class="btn btn-primary filter-button" data-filter="accesorios">Accesorios</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="row animate-box">
      <div class="col-md-4 filter mesas">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter syb mesas">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter escritorios">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter syb mesas">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter escritorios syb">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter mesas">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter accesorios">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter ratonas">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice una clase adicional que se llama `active_li` que tiene las caracteristicas de `.archive-producto ul .btn:active,`.
Lo único que se hace es que cuando detectas el click se quita la clase de todos los elementos y se lo agregamos al que se dió click.

Saludos

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      $(".filter-button").click(function(){
            
            
            //Pirmero ciclas todos los filtros para quitar la clase de todos los elementos
            $('.filter-button').each(function(){
              $(this).removeClass('active_li');
            });
            
            //Luego le pones la clase al seleccionado
            $(this).addClass('active_li');
            
            var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
          
          if(value == "all")
          {
              //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
              $('.filter').show('1000');
          }
          else
          {
  //            $('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
  //            $(".filter").not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').addClass('hidden');
              $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
              $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');
              
          }
      });

  });
```

```css
.archive-producto ul .btn:active,
.archive-producto ul .btn:focus,
.active_li{
  color: red!important
}

.archive-producto ul .btn{
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.archive-producto .port-image{
  width: 100%;
}
.archive-producto .col-md-4{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.product .product-grid {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.product .product-grid .sale {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #c70707;
    color: #fffbfa;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
}
.product .product-grid .inner {
  display: table;
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.product .product-grid .inner p .icon {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #d1c286;
}
.product .product-grid .inner p .icon:hover, .product .product-grid .inner p .icon:focus {
  color: #d1c286;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.product .desc h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.product .desc h3 a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="archive-producto">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="row animate-box">
      <ul class="categoria">
        <li class="btn filter-button" data-filter="all">Todos</li>
        <li class="btn filter-button" data-filter="mesas">Mesas</li>
        <li class="btn filter-button" data-filter="syb">Sillas y bancos</li>
        <li class="btn filter-button" data-filter="escritorios">Escritorio</li>
        <li class="btn filter-button" data-filter="ratonas">Mesa ratonas</li>
        <li class="btn filter-button" data-filter="accesorios">Accesorios</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="row animate-box">
      <div class="col-md-4 filter mesas">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter syb mesas">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter escritorios">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter syb mesas">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter escritorios syb">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter mesas">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter accesorios">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 filter ratonas">
        <div class="product">
          <div class="product-grid" style="background-image:url(http://www.templates4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Engon-Joomla-Corporate-Portfolio-Template.jpg);">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <a href="single.html" class="icon"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3><a href="single.html">Hauteville Concrete Rocking Chair</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda Alberto